# How do I submit Data as Form-Data with cUrl

Tags: php

I have to send Data to an Api via PHP cUrl and then save the Token I get as a response.
In postman in works when I send the data as Form-data, but not if I send it as raw body. I now try to send the data via cUrl but I get the same response I get when I use postman with raw-body. How do I post it as form data?

Thanks

I tried those:

1. try:

   ```
   $body = array();
   $body['userEmail'] = $email;
   $body['userPassword'] = $password;
   $body['clientId'] = 'Kursapp';

   $data_string = json_encode($body);

   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
       'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'
   ));
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

   $response = curl_exec($curl);

   curl_close ($curl);
   ```
2. try:

   ```
   $body = array();
   $body['userEmail'] = $email;
   $body['userPassword'] = $password;
   $body['clientId'] = 'Kursapp';

   $data_string = http_build_query($body);

   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
       'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'
   ));
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

   $response = curl_exec($curl);

   curl_close ($curl);
   ```
3. try

   ```
   $body = array();
   $body['userEmail'] = $email;
   $body['userPassword'] = $password;
   $body['clientId'] = 'Kursapp';

   $post_str ='';
   foreach ($body as $key=>$value){
       $post_str .= $key.'='.urldecode($value).'&';
   }
   $post_str = substr($post_str, 0, -1);

   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
       'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'
   ));
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postr);

   $response = curl_exec($curl);

   curl_close ($curl);
   ```
4. try with guzzle

   ```
   $client = new Client();

   $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
       'headers' => [
           'Accept' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
           'Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
       ],
       'form_params' => $body
   ]);
   ```

Comment: *hint* In Postman there is `code` button next to your params, there you can export request as cUrl. About your code. Maybe because you say that you are sending JSON: `Content-Type: application/json` instead of form-data header?

Comment: omg the code postman provided worked! now I just have to adjust the parameters. thank you!

Comment: about your question, yes that could be. Postman changed it to form-data/multipart

Comment: Yes, your headers are wrong